# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [BigChainDB]

Tags: python-3.x, bigchaindb

I Got This error when working with bigchaindb

I was following this documentation: 
https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/py-driver/en/master/usage.html

And I got this error when i type this line ,

sent_creation_tx = bdb.transactions.send_commit(fulfilled_creation_tx)

Everything before that works fine.
Dont know how to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the "remote host" is.

Where are you trying to send the `fulfilled_creation_tx`? To a BigchainDB node on your local machine (localhost)? To the BigchainDB Testnet? Somewhere else? The answer to that question will determine your "BigchainDB Root URL". Here is a page to help you determine the BigchainDB Root URL in your case: http://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/py-driver/en/latest/connect.html

Comment: I am trying it to BigChainDB Testnet